# ProgressDialog Not Dismissing in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an app that propogates a spinner from a website inside an AsyncTask. Without a ProgressDialog, I am stuck with an empty spinner until it loads. With a ProgressDialog, the network operation never finishes and the ProgressDialog stays up forever. Here is my code:

```
class TheaterGetter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {   
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public TheaterGetter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage(((Activity) context).getString(R.string.loading_theaters));
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected Document doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://landmarkcinemas.com").timeout(10000).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("landmark cinemas connection error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return doc;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
        Element allOptions = doc.select("select[id=campaign").first();
        Elements options = allOptions.getElementsByTag("option");
        options.remove(0);
        TreeMap<String, String> theaters = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        for (Element option:options) {
            theaters.put(option.html(), option.attr("value"));
        }
        final TreeMapSpinAdapter adapter = new TreeMapSpinAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, theaters);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                MainActivity.setTheater((String) adapter.getItem(pos));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is related to your problem, but you should parse the Document inside `doInBackground`, and return the result `theaters` so `onPostExecute` can show them on the UI. Parsing might take some time to run, so you should avoid doing it on the UI thread.

Comment: Oh. For some reason I thought it would be good to use the doInBackground sparingly but I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rearrange the dismiss dialog line as follows :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {

    dialog.dismiss();   // rearranged

    Element allOptions = doc.select("select[id=campaign").first();
    Elements options = allOptions.getElementsByTag("option");
    options.remove(0);
    TreeMap<String, String> theaters = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    for (Element option:options) {
        theaters.put(option.html(), option.attr("value"));
    }
    final TreeMapSpinAdapter adapter = new TreeMapSpinAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, theaters);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            MainActivity.setTheater((String) adapter.getItem(pos));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}
```